# Finding the total number of possible matches

Tags: combinatorics

Consider six players $P_1, P_2, P_3, P_4, P_5$ and $P_6$. A team consists of two players.
(Thus, there are $15$ distinct teams.) Two teams play a match exactly once if there is no common player. For example, team $\{P_1, P_2\}$ can not play with $\{P_2, P_3\}$ but will play with $\{P_4, P_5\}$. Then the total number of possible matches is?

I've tried to count it in an easy way but I always end up getting confused, can someone help?

Comment: Hint: how many teams could you oppose to the team $\{P&1,P_2\}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: how many teams does $\{P_1,P_2\}$ have to play? The answer is the same for each team. If you add up the number of matches played by each team, you have counted every match twice.

Answer (score 2):

A match must be played among four different players.

There are $\binom 6 4 = 15$ different ways to choose four different players.

With any chosen four players, there are exactly three matches to be played (just pair one of them with any of the other three).

Hence the total number of matches is $15 \times 3 = 45$.

Answer (score 1):

You can see that pair $\{P_1,P_2\}$ plays aganst every pair of the other four that is ${4\choose 2}=6$. So e the total number of plays is $${1\over2}{6\choose 2}\cdot 6$$

We have to divide by two because we count every play twice.